# Perform action based on order of events in observable sequences

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

I have three (or more) observable sequences of `bool`:

```
IObservable<bool> a0 = ...;
IObservable<bool> a1 = ...;
IObservable<bool> a2 = ...;
```

These sequences generate mostly `false` values but once in a while there is a `true` (the sequences can also be empty). I'm not interested in the values themselves but rather in the order of the `true` values. So if `a0` is `true`, then `a2` is true and finally `a1`, I'd like to perform some action:

```
(a0, a2, a1) => ...do something...
```

But if the `true` values appear in another order, I'd like to do something else:

```
(a2, a1, a0) => ...do something else...
(a0, a1, a2) => ...do something entirely else...
```

So I'm only interested in the first `true` value of each sequence and depending on the order in which they occur, I'd like to perform some action.

I could record the timestamp of each first occurrence of `true` and then sort in a `CombineLatest` call, but I have a feeling there is a better way. One problem with this approach is that I am now dependent on granularity of recorded timestamps.

Comment: Can they fire a `true` again before any other observable fires a true? Is this a 'rolling' match, or do you start all over once all three have matched?

Comment: I'm only interested in the very first `true` value. After that, I dispose of the observer(s).

Comment: I've given an answer based on this and some other naive assumptions. However, the overall method should translate into a number of scenarios.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, you only need the true values so ignore the rest. Second, you can encode each observable into a more semantic meaning (perhaps a string?). Third, you can then merge these streams, wait for 3 values to arrive, and act based on them.

Set up:

```
var a0 = new Subject<bool>();
var a1 = new Subject<bool>();
var a2 = new Subject<bool>();
```

Encoding:

```
var a0t = a0.Where(x => x).Select(x => "a0").Take(1); // thanks Matthew Finlay
var a1t = a1.Where(x => x).Select(x => "a1").Take(1);
var a2t = a2.Where(x => x).Select(x => "a2").Take(1);
```

Merge and get after three values:

```
var merged = a0t.Merge(a1t).Merge(a2t);
var message = merged.Buffer(3).Subscribe(x => ProcessMessage(String.Join("", x)));
```

The processing section:

```
public void ProcessMessage(string message)
{
    switch(message) {
        case "a0a1a2": Console.WriteLine("1"); break;
        case "a1a2a0": Console.WriteLine("2"); break;
        case "a2a1a0": Console.WriteLine("3"); break;
    }
}
```

And test:

```
a1.OnNext(true);
a2.OnNext(true);
a0.OnNext(true);
```

Comment: Nice :) I can definitely translate this to my specific situation.

Comment: If you add a Take(1) to the definitions of a0t, a1t and a2t it will dispose of them after the first true value.

Comment: It may be useful to be able to dynamically manage the message actions, so can I suggest that you avoid the `ProcessMessage` method and create separate `Where` clause Observables that you subscribe to?